# TextInputEditText Error Icon Doesn't Appears

Tags: android, layout

I'm facing a problem with TextInputLayout PasswordToggle, When i display error on TextInputEditText the red error icon appears on the top of the password toggle icon, so i solved this problem by hiding the password toggle when displaying the error but now the red error icon doesn't appear, only the error message appears when i click on the EditText.
can any one help me solve this issue?

**Here is my Login Screen**

[image]

**This is after clicking on Sign In Button**

[image]

**This is after clicking on TextInputEditText**

[image]

Hint: if i clicked for the next time on the Sign In Button the red icon will appear

**This is after clicking on TextInputEditText for the second time**

[image]

Here is the Password Layout code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/phone_layout"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/phone_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_layout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/password"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_user_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/hidepassword"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white"
                setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled="@{loginViewModel.inputValidation.isError}">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_user_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:hint="@string/password_text"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:text="@={loginViewModel.loginParams.password}"
                    app:error="@{loginViewModel.inputValidation.passwordError}"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of sending screenshots of the code. Consider pasting them here.

Comment: this is my first time asking a question here, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting error on your `TextInputEditText` set on the `TextInputLayout`, so in your case the view with id `layout_user_password`.

Comment: unfortunately i'm committed to the design,, But i'll take your solution in my consideration, thank you for your help

Comment: What? This has nothing to do with your design. When you are setting the "This field is required" error you are setting in the `input_user_password`, set it on your `layout_user_password` view instead.

Comment: I understand your point of view but when i tried it the error message appeared under the TextInputEditText and that wasn't matching with the design somehow ..